# Вставка значение в sql таблицу

Tags: sql, insert

При попытке вставить в табл City название города, дает ошибку:

> [Исключение, код ошибки 30 000, SQLState 23502] Столбец 'COUNTRYID' не
>   может принять нулевое значение (NULL)

Почему так?

```
create table Contacts.Country
(
    ID int not null unique generated always as identity(start with 1, increment by 1),
    Name varchar(150) primary key
);

create table Contacts.City
(
    ID int not null unique generated always as identity(start with 1, increment by 1),
    Name varchar(50),
    CountryID int, 
    constraint PK_City primary key(Name, CountryID),
    constraint FK_City_Country foreign key(CountryID) references Country (ID)
)
;
insert into Country(Name) values ('Russia');
insert into City(Name) values ('Omsk');
```

Comment: `CountryID int null,` или `insert into City(CountryID, Name) values (1, 'Omsk')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании таблицы вы написали `constraint PK_City primary key(Name, CountryID),`. У вас получился составной ключ из двух значений. Никакая часть составного ключа не может быть `null`. Вы же вставляете значение только в колонку `Name`, отсюда и ошибка.

У вас есть колонка `Id`, ее и используйте в качестве первичного ключа. Если вам дополнительно необходимо следить за уникальностью пары `Name, CountryId` лучше использовать констрейнт `unique`

Comment: Но ведь CountryID в следующем констрейнте ссылается на ID из табл Country, которые на каждую новую страну инкрементируется. Я думал в City явно указывать нужно только имя. ID инкрементируется просто, а CountryID ,берется из предыдущей табл, раз оно ссылается на табл Country?

Comment: Внешний ключ работает не так. Когда вы указываете внешний ключ, проверяется что строчка с таким первичным ключом есть в таблице на которую этот ключ ссылается. При этом в таблицу с ключом значения не вставляются.

Comment: ах вот оно что.Спасибо.кажется картинка вырисовывается более понятная. Теперь при insert into City(Name,CountryID) values ('Omsk',1);
 все ок, только непонятно почему ID в City считает с 5

Comment: @Montego Похоже, элементы из последовательности извлекались даже при неудачной вставке.  Если `ID=5`, значит до этого вы неудачно 4 раза пытались вставить